# Jquery - Unable to auto insert dashes in Chrome, I.E. After Clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm new to the Jquery world and am having an issue with the code below. I'm hoping you can let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SocialSecurity').on('input', function () {
            var newNum = jQuery('#SocialSecurity');
            if (newNum.val().contains("x")) {
                newNum.val("");
            }    newNum.clone().attr('alt','999-99-9999').insertAfter('#SocialSecurity').prev().remove();
            $('#SocialSecurity').focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The issue I am having is that my application has a SSN box which on page load,for security reasons, is populated xxx-xx-9999. However, if a user wants to update it I am attempting to clone the box, but changing the format to 999-99-9999.

The code above works fine in Firefox, however in Chrome and all versions of I.E. the field is not auto-inserting the dashes for the SSN. This causes the authentication to fail.

A few changes I've tried after research that have not worked are,

Changing the attr() to prop()
Changing the $ to Javascript

I appreciate any advice you can give me. Also let me know if I need to provide any additional information/code.

Regards,

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Also, why are you cloning, updating, and replacing the original instead of just updating the original?

Comment: Well I'm not entirely sure why we are cloning. This was the existing code in place when I took it over. I'm hoping to get an answer from the higher ups a bit later. I will post any updates as soon as I can.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want to happen? The initial display is xxx-xx-9999 (with the 9's being the users actual last 4)? You're wanting the user to be able to replace the x's with numbers, but keep the format?

Comment: Yes. What we're hoping to have happen is the initial display is xxx-xx-9999. If the user needs to update that number they would enter 999-99-9999. The box would then change the format from xxx-xx-9999 to 999-99-9999. I believe this is why we are cloning and then destroying the initial box. We weren't able to change the box format after the page load. This is working as intended when I run in FF, but not in Chrome or I.E.

Comment: Just to add to the previous statement, We are able to type numbers in all web browsers, however FireFox is the only browser that is reading the attr('alt','999-99-9999') line and inserting the the dashes. The other browsers only show the numbers (999999999)

Comment: You may just need to change your event call to : `$(document).on('input', '#SocialSecurity', function() { ... });` and then you can get rid of `$(document).ready();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to do.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXNMe/1)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#SocialSecurity').on('input', function () {
         var $ss = $(this);
         var ssval = $ss.val();
         if (ssval.indexOf("x") > -1) {
             $ss.val("");
         } else {
             ssval = ssval.split(/\D+/g).join('');
             ssvals = ssval.match(/(\d{1,3})(?:(\d{1,2})(\d{1,4})?)?/);
             if (ssvals) {
                 ssvals.shift();
                 ssval = ssvals.filter(Boolean).join("-");
             }
             $ss.val(ssval);
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: That did it. Appreciate the help everyone!  This actually helps with another issue too.

Comment: @Forie25, out of curiosity... what else did this help with?

Comment: Actually for personal use. I'm trying to create some simple apps to help familiarize myself if JS/Jquery. Used this script has a map of sorts to add/update ssn/dob/phone number fields.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8Rjx/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SocialSecurity').on('input', function () {
            var newNum = jQuery('#SocialSecurity');
            if (newNum.val().indexOf("x")) {
                newNum.val("");
            }    newNum.clone().val('999-99-9999').insertAfter('#SocialSecurity').prev().remove();
            $('#SocialSecurity').focus();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. I'm getting familiar with jsFiddle now. It appears that script is on input change, adding all 9's. When I remove them it still does not auto input the dashes.